# What does the man in the soup say exactly?

Tags: slang

In this [video - Soup Leprechaun](https://youtu.be/A9au3KFLXX8?t=62) the man in the soup says something I cannot understand.

Can a native speaker please help me with that?

Is it:

1. would you like my pod of gold
2. would you like my part of gold
3. *...something different...*

Please be careful, the video gets really loud at 1min50.

Comment: [Leprechauns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leprechaun) have a *pot of gold* hidden at the end of the rainbow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized (about a very specific problem that no other user of this site is likely to have).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell but it sounds like "would you like me pot of gold?"

It's spoken by a [leprechaun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leprechaun). Wikipedia says:

> A leprechaun (Irish: leipreachán/luchorpán) is a type of fairy of the
>   Aos Sí in Irish folklore. They are usually depicted as little bearded
>   men, wearing a coat and hat, who partake in mischief. They are
>   solitary creatures who spend their time making and mending shoes and
>   have a hidden pot of gold at the end of the rainbow.

*Me* here means "my" and is (presumably) representing the way this would be said in the Irish dialect. In which case it's probably better written as:

> *Would you like me pot o' gold?*

The customer is tempted by the offer, and the leprechaun, somewhat predictably, provides a mischievous outcome. The customer could have tested whether it's true that a captured leprechaun will purchase their freedom by granting three wishes, but perhaps the leprechaun's fate demonstrates why we don't get reliable data on this.